# Selecting value from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two rows from database based on particular id

```
ID         Address    Res_Address     Office_Address
-------------------------------------------------
4          C 60            0               1
4          D 90            1               0
```

I just want to select Address having flag res_address 1 in ResAddress And flag having Office_address 1 As OfficeAddress by select statement.
I don't want to use stored procedure.

Comment: You might need to expand on this slightly.  Why do you have two users with the same ID?  Is it always Rahul as user1 and Vikram as user2, or could this change?

Comment: Agree that more details are needed. If it's just two, you could SELECT MAX(value) AS user1, MIN(value) AS user2 FROM <tablename> GROUP BY id. But this is kind of hacky.

Comment: You can take it like this.Actually ID is addressID. I will always get two rows in which one row will have office address of that person and other row will have residence address based on flag in rows. So i just want to select these two address that office address and residence address.

Comment: What RDBMS (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, ...) are you using?

Comment: Provide more table content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT ID,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Res_Address    = 1 THEN Address END) ResidentAddress,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Office_Address = 1 THEN Address END) OfficeAddress
FROM 
(
  SELECT -- your subquery that returns two rows goes here
) q
 GROUP BY ID
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | RESIDENTADDRESS | OFFICEADDRESS |
----------------------------------------
|  4 |            D 90 |          C 60 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9936/1)** demo

**UPDATE** If I understand correctly your comment you can use `COALESCE()` for that

```
SELECT ID,
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Res_Address = 1    THEN Address END), '0') ResidentAddress,
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Office_Address = 1 THEN Address END), '0') OfficeAddress
FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM Table1
) q
 GROUP BY ID
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ffc7/1)** demo

Comment: Just for addition if my query returns only one row. Having Res_Address and Ofc_Address as 0 and 0